# Nginx: one port to multiple IP fowarding

Tags: nginx, portforwarding

I am new to Nginx, and I am looking to have my router port forward a No Machine remote access (NX) request to a Nginx server which would then forward the request again to the correct Virtual Machine for viewing. I am trying to do this because my router only allows one port to one IP forwarding. I want one port to multiple IP forwarding. How would one go about doing this? The issue seems to be that No Machine only allows me to specify my router IP and no way of having Nginx know which machine to forward the request to that it is given from the router.

Comment: Does NoMachine uses http for connectiong? I doubt it, so nginx will not be any help.

Comment: No Machine uses NX. Do you know of something else instead of Nginx I can use to accomplish what I said above? Thank you.

Comment: I guess there is no way. The idea of "hosts" exists in http (and partly in ftp) protocols. Others just uses ip:port pair and sends nothing more that could help to choose between virtual machines (in you case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NginX is of no use here. It will work for HTTP and HTTPS , so Ignore it.

What you're actually thinking of is [Port address translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Port_address_translation). However PAT will work only when the connection is initiated from the secured side (your virtual machines in this case). So again, this is not helpful either.

The only other possible way is to have individual [1-to-1 NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Basic_NAT). Not sure about the type of router you have, but I had done something similar in the past using IPTables.

Besides, this question is more suited to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) where you might get better responses than on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll try to ask it there. My router is an Apple Airport 2nd gen, which only allows one port to one IP forwarding.

Comment: This question is not suited for ServerFault, which is for professional sysadmins. Please don't refer home/hobby questions there - they belong more on SuperUser.